MongoDB get rows with $lookup like field from related collections
i have 2 collections :

users
db.users.insert({ _id: 1, username: 'mark' });
db.users.insert({ _id: 2, username: 'leon' });
db.users.insert({ _id: 3, username: 'leontin'});


data
db.data.insert(
{
  _id: ObjectId('6675309f82bdfbe3b00febfa'),
  user: 1,
  message: '94451 Laos Sweden Iran',
});
db.data.insert(
{
  _id: ObjectId('6675309f82bdfbe3b00febfb'),
  user: 2,
  message: 'message  22222',
});
db.data.insert( 
{
  _id: ObjectId('6675309f82bdfbe3b00febfc'),
  user: 3,
  message: 'message  3333',
});



if i search :
db.data.aggregate([{'$lookup' : {"from" :"users", "localField" : "user", "foreignField" : "_id", "as" : "user_info"}}, {'$match' : {'user_info.username' : 'leon'}}]);


is working good.
But i need to get all result  where username  like   '^leo%' 
Any help, thanx in advance.
Regards I.

Hi, can I know what you are trying to query especially the regex with %? Start with leo? As your current regex finds the document with the username starting with "leo%".

After the lookup, do $unwind: "$user_info" and change the $match part to: { $match: { $expr: { $regexMatch: { input: "$user_info.username" , regex: "^leo", options: "i" } } } }. The ^leo part means "starts with 'leo'" and options "i" means case-insensitive. Docs for $regexMatch

@aneroid   you have right
db.data.aggregate([{'$lookup' : {"from" :"users", "localField" : "user", "foreignField" : "_id", "as" : "user_info"}}, {'$unwind': "$user_info"}, { $match: { $expr: { $regexMatch: { input: "$user_info.username" , regex: "^leo", options: "i" } } } }]);


@amic Yes, that's what I mean. If it worked, you can post that as an answer to your own question. Actually, you can even use a lookup pipeline to keep matches in the lookup itself.

@amic Not sure what you need help with. Your comment above has the correct pipeline & results. I've added an answer below explaining why "lookup + unwind + match" is better than doing "lookup with pipeline containing match + unwind".

The preferred way to do it is as per my comment and your solution with that:
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user_info"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$user_info"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: "$user_info.username",
          regex: "^leo",
          options: "i"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
The aggregation pipeline above is better than the next one below:

the first one is cleaner, easier to read, and to debug.
MongoDB optimises $unwind stages on the target field of a $lookup stage if it's immediately after the lookup.
And MongoDB optimises even more fully with lookup + unwind + match. See $lookup,  $unwind, and  $match  Coalescence
You can also use a lookup pipeline to reduce the results during the lookup itself but this is unnecessary (and ugly). See my note below about MongoDB optimisations.

As an example of what NOT to do:
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user_info",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $regexMatch: {
                input: "$username",
                regex: "^leo",
                options: "i"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$user_info" }
])

Mongo Playground

can you check this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78652408/mongodb-find-data-between-multiple-related-collections

@amic If that helped, read: What should I do when someone answers my question?, and about accepting and voting.
