MongoDB find data between multiple related collections
I have 3 collections :
users
[
    { _id: 1, username: 'mark' },
    { _id: 2, username: 'leon' },
    { _id: 3, username: 'leontin'}
]

providers
[
    { _id: 1, name: 'prov1' },
    { _id: 2, name: 'prov2' },
    { _id: 3, name: 'prov3' },
    { _id: 39, name: 'prov39' }
]

data
[
    {
      _id: ObjectId('6675309f82bdfbe3b00febfa'),
      user: 1,
      provider: 1,
      message: '94451 Laos Sweden Iran',
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId('6675309f82bdfbe3b00febfb'),
      user: 2,
      provider: 3,
      message: 'message  22222',
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId('6675309f82bdfbe3b00febfc'),
      user: 3,
      provider: 39,
      message: 'message  3333',
    }
]

If i search like this, it's working correctly:
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "user",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "user_info"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$user_info"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: "$user_info.username",
          regex: "^leo",
          options: "i"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

But i need to add more to this query: where provider.name like '^prov3':
I have added the related collection but I can't add the "like"
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "user",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "user_info"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$user_info"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "providers",
      "localField": "provider",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "provider_info"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$provider_info"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: "$user_info.username",
          regex: "^leo",
          options: "i"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])


In your $match stage, you should have the $and operator to match the document based on the user_info.username and provider_info.name criteria.
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "user",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "user_info"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "providers",
      "localField": "provider",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "provider_info"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: {
                $first: "$user_info.username"
              },
              regex: "^leo",
              options: "i"
            }
          },
          {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: {
                $first: "$provider_info.name"
              },
              regex: "^prov3",
              options: "i"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Demo @ Mongo Playground

Hi @Yong Shun,
i have a data collection with 3.200.000 entries (i need more), 20.000 users, 10.000 providers, searching is about 15+ seconds for this 2 related fields.
How to improve the search (i have index in each field, data.user, data.provider, and users.username, providers.name)  ?

This could be done in a similar way to the answer to your previous question.
Since you want both checks ^leo and ^prov3, do "lookup + unwind + match" for userInfo and then do a "lookup + unwind + match" for providers. This ensures that results match both criteria. Also, by doing the triple-stage together, there are fewer documents which need to go through the rest of the pipeline.
And each sequence is highly optimised by MongoDB: $lookup, $unwind, and $match Coalescence.
db.data.aggregate([
  // lookup + unwind + match `user_info`
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user_info"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$user_info" },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: "$user_info.username",
          regex: "^leo",
          options: "i"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // lookup + unwind + match `provider_info`
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "providers",
      localField: "provider",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "provider_info"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$provider_info" },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: "$provider_info.name",
          regex: "^prov3",
          options: "i"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Hi @aneroid,
i have a data collection with 3.200.000 entries (i need more), 20.000 users, 10.000 providers, searching is about 20+ seconds for this 2 related fields.
How to improve the search (i have index in each field, data.user, data.provider, and users.username, providers.name)  ?

Does it take 20 seconds to fetch all the records or just to execute the query before getting the first 100 results (or whatever is your default cursor size)? Also, note that Case-insensitive indexes typically do not improve performance for $regex queries. If you don't need case-insensitive matches, then remove the options: i part.
